# Color vs Colour (and other words with similar multiple spellings)

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-naming

How should the US vs UK color (mis)spelling be handled?  I've already seen both several times, and I can foresee this being a big issue with doubled tags.

I for one vote for sticking to color instead of colour for tagging simply because it's less to type.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another one for only one tag - and I would say color as there are likely to be a lot more north americans using the site. (And I speak as a British person).

And I agree with gabr that in the questions and answers either spelling should be allowed.

Comment: FWIW, it's really only the US that spell it "color"; we Canadians officially use "colour" too. (Thanks, UK.) Still, I'd guess that the number of Americans (including on this site) would be greater than the number of non-Americans, and thus "color" would be more popular.

Comment: I'm used to using color as a programmer, even though I am British.

Comment: I'm British and (somewhat unfortunately) I've had to become used to spelling it "color". Once tag synonyms are implemented this should be a non-issue, anyhoo.

Answer (score 5):

There should definitely be only one tag (color / colour). As for which one - it is all the same to me as I'm not from UK nor US.

As for the questions/answers any spelling should be allowed.

Comment: +1 for the any spelling allowed in Q/As. On another SE site I'm a member of I feel very left out as a Brit. A lot more of the posts assume a knowledge of American culture and terminology - we seem to do a much better job of being inclusive here, and letting people use their native variant of English is a part of that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as a Canadian, we tend to the British spelling. I will note that it is, after all, *English* and named after the country of origin, so they're clearly the best source for the correct spelling. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm an American but I prefer to spell colour the British way.

However, for a tag you should probably use the simplest and shortest spelling for tags, it should be auto-completed past "colo" anyway...