# Image Stabilization or Vibration Reduction

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-naming

Just wondering if we want to have just one tag for Image Stabilization/Vibration Reduction/Vibration Compensation/Optical Stabilisation.

I think we should have just the one, and I think it should **image-stabilization** - but I'm open to something else. I note [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/804/how-does-image-stabilization-vibration-reduction-work) has used four tags:

- image-stabilization
- vibration-reduction
- is
- vr

I think the initials are definitely bad. And I would also go with stabilization rather than stabilisation (following the voting on [this question](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48/color-vs-colour-and-other-words-with-similar-multiple-spellings/)).

Answer (score 6):

In a similar way to what I suggested [here](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/tagging-with-brand-names), I think we should use one, generic, descriptive tag for the overall subject, which personally I think should be `[image-stabilization]`, although I am open to other suggestions (To me these systems don't reduce vibration, in the most part, but stabilise the image to compensate for the vibration).

In the (rarer) case that there is a question about a specific detail of one brands system, then I would suggest using the name of the system (so `[is]` for Canon, `[vr]` for Nikon, etc.), possibly in addition to the main `[image-stabilization]` tag (or whatever it ends up being).

Alternatively, you could of course tag your question `[nikon] [image-stabilization]` if you had a Nikon-specific question. You'll probably end up tagging it with `[nikon]` anyway, and it's one less tag than `[nikon] [vr] [image-stabilization]`.

Comment: Important to use the terms people use - I suspect Nikon-heads won't think to seach for [nikon] [image-stabilization]; instead, they'll search for [vr].

Comment: +1 for [image-stabilization].  I know it's Canon's term, but it seems to describe the concept best.  Similarly, I voted for [speedlight] for flash questions, even though it's Nikon's term.

Comment: @Eddie Deyo - I agree on both counts, as I mentioned in the speedlight/speedlite thread (http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/118/what-term-should-we-adopt-for-speedlights-speedlites). Is there any set way that we decide what we're going to go with on these matters? There doesn't seem to be any clear winners in either thread.

Comment: I googled dpreview.com and a few other sites with numerous camera reviews, and 'image stabilization' definitely seems to be a fairly generic term, regardless of the model being described.  I'd say it's pretty safe.

Answer (score 2):

If there are questions regarding a vendor's implementation of the concept, that implementation should be a tag. Nikon has VR, Canon has IS. They do much the same thing, yet have different names. To avoid tag wars, we should probably use whichever is relevant to the question.

Comment: But then we're reducing the amount of information the average Canon/Nikon/other-brand user has access too. As a Canon user, I would instinctively browse the [image-stabilization] or [is] tags, and would miss out all of the information that may well be equally relevant to my generic query about reducing camera-shake that was tagged [vibration-reduction] or [vr]. There is a place for specific tags, but I think we need one generic tag per major subject area.

Answer (score 0):

Canon calls it Image Stabilization; Nikon calls it Vibration Reduction.  If we pick one or the other, we're going to make someone cranky.  The other issue is that there will likely be questions specific to Canon or Nikon's particular version of stabilization, in which case one would need to use the correct tag.

I included the initials but I'm certainly ok with the community deciding that's bad practice.