# Do we need composite tags, or will combinations of tags suffice?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-naming

Looking again at [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/840/dx-or-fx-lenses), which I re-tagged earlier to use more generic tags as described [here](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/tagging-with-brand-names), I'm now trying to decide whether we need the `[dx-vs-fx]` tag. Whatever happens, I believe it should be replaced with a non-branded version, but if that discussion could be kept to [the other question](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/tagging-with-brand-names) and this question be left to discuss the following:

Do we need "composite" tags, when both of the items that make up the tag are already included as other tags? I'm all for removing the `[dx-vs-fx]` tag all together, as anyone who wants to find questions comparing the two could search for both the `[cropped-sensor]` and `[full-frame]` tags, possibly with `[nikon]` if the brand mattered. In my mind there would be no need to have, for example, a `[canon-flash]` tag, as you'd just tag your question with `[canon]` and `[flash]`.

Other examples I've seen are things [like `[canon-eos]`](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canon-eos) on questions also tagged `[canon]` and `[dslr]`. I know you can get pre-eos cameras, but they're not the norm, and so perhaps I can see a justification for having a `[canon-fd]` tag, but `[canon-eos]` seems redundant.

Comment: I see what you're getting at, but I think dx-vs-fx is a poor example, since that question is getting specifically at the crop (APS-C) vs. full-frame (35mm) decision/planning process, which isn't captured by the simple composition of the dx and fx tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the interest of disclosure; I'd actually retagged that question to include `[nikon]` (at the expense of `[format]`, which didn't seem as relevant).

I like the idea of some composite tags, after all there is a limit of five tags on questions. I think it's important to include the brand when the question is specific (Such as the one in question above) and there is potential to have a hierarchy that reflects the ranges within a brand (So maybe `[canon-ixus]` if someone wanted to know something specific to that particular range of compact cameras). After all, the interesting/ignored tags support wildcards, so `[canon*]` would highlight (or hide) the composites just as well.

Perhaps the best approach would be to be monitor which tags get used, and merge those that are too specific.